# Azure DataBricks - Deequ - Finding Rows that failed on a check

Tags: scala, azure-databricks, amazon-deequ

I followed https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/test-data-quality-at-scale-with-deequ/
and got running with the checks and verification etc.

But I am not able to find out , on which rows exactly my data is failing.
That is a very important part , that I need the rows which have failed the check.

I tried following : https://github.com/awslabs/deequ/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/amazon/deequ/schema/RowLevelSchemaValidatorTest.scala
But, I am getting error databricks while running codes from this link :

```
error: object SparkContextSpec is not a member of package com.amazon.deequ
import com.amazon.deequ.SparkContextSpec
       ^
command-4342528364312961:24: error: not found: type SparkContextSpec
class RowLevelSchemaValidatorTest extends WordSpec with SparkContextSpec {
                                                        ^
command-4342528364312961:28: error: not found: value withSparkSession
    "correctly enforce null constraints" in withSparkSession { sparkSession =>
                                            ^
command-4342528364312961:39: error: not found: value RowLevelSchema
      val schema = RowLevelSchema()
                   ^
command-4342528364312961:40: error: not found: value isNullable
        .withIntColumn("id", isNullable = false)
```

And the list goes on.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems you are encountering are likely due to an incorrect project setup. Are you running the tests from your IDE? If not, I would recommend you make sure that the code, in IntelliJ for example, compiles. The unit-tests should then be executable from there.

IntelliJ comes with a Maven plugin that allows importing projects.

Comment: I am trying to run through the notebooks provided by AzureDatabricks.

Comment: I would assume that the test package `com.amazon.deequ.SparkContextSpec` is not shipped as part of the notebook. If the notebook environment provides a `SparkContext` you could this one instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.amazon.deequ.schema.{RowLevelSchema,RowLevelSchemaValidator}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType, StringType, TimestampType}
import org.scalatest.WordSpec
import spark.implicits

val data = Seq(
        ("123", "Product A", "2012-07-22 22:59:59"),
        ("N/A", "Product B", null),
        ("456", null, "2012-07-22 22:59:59"),
        (null, "Product C", "2012-07-22 22:59:59")
      ).toDF("id", "name", "event_time")

val schema = RowLevelSchema()
.withIntColumn("id", isNullable = false)
.withStringColumn("name", maxLength = Some(10))
.withTimestampColumn("event_time", mask = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", isNullable = false)

val result = RowLevelSchemaValidator.validate(data, schema)

assert(result.numValidRows == 2)
val validIds = result.validRows.select("id").collect.map { _.getInt(0) }.toSet
assert(validIds.size == result.numValidRows)
assert(validIds.contains(123))
assert(validIds.contains(456))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).